# Move string from user form to active cell that called the form

Tags: excel, userform, vba

Currently, my code opens up a user form when a specific cell is clicked. What I would like is to move the string inputed into a textbox within the user form to be moved to the cell that was clicked to load the form in the first place.
This is the code to call the form:

```
dim x as integer
For x = 5 To 100
    If Target.Address = "$AY$" & x Then
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
Next x
```

So for example, the user clicks cell AY10, the form opens, they input the string into TextBox1. Then, what I need is when they click a submit button (Button1), the string is moved into cell AY10, the cell that was clicked to initially open the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
Selection.Value = UserForm1.Textbox1.value
```

should do it

Comment: OP can put this in an exit button click on the form or something like that.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you! I think I was over complicating things in my head

Answer (score 1):

On the front end; to open the form change everything you are showing to:

```
if not intersect(target,Range("AY5:AY100") is nothing then UserForm1.Show
```

That removes the loop.

On the back end you do what Dirk has proposed but another way is to pass the target.address into a shared public variable

```
publicVarRange = Target
```

Then instead of using selection you can call the range from the variable.

```
publicVarRange.value = textbox.value
```

This way if during the exchange the selected cell changes it will still put the value in the correct cell.